# Progress Indicators: Their History and Usage

Tags: user-interface, loading, history, progress, indicator

I am undertaking a research project into progress indicators (I may expand into more elements of GUI) and am looking to gather as much material as possible on them in terms of graphic design (not looking for coding etc.) and their appearance in history and their use today.

I'm asking for help in finding any examples of progress indicators in the past, I believe the Xerox Parc was the first GUI so assuming that will be the first place a progress indicator would be found in this context. I'm also after any help in locating written articles about them. Basically anything you can think of relevant to progress indicators in any context, computers, video games, including their usage today (I will be doing a survey of current trends and developments of PIs).

Anything is helpful, thanks in advance!

Isaac

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software history.

Comment: Issac there is a programmers site :)

Answer (score 0):

Good old Robert Bell wrote a really good article on this subject.

http://chrisharrison.net/projects/progressbars/ProgBarHarrison.pdf

I also heard somewhere that some software actually delays from progress bar as if the user thinks that the software has installed or loaded really quick there was an issue but I cannot find anything which explains it in further details.

Something I just read

> Progress bars shouldn't be based on time, they should be based on
>   quantity of work. Typically when they do the marquee style of progress
>   bar (where it just show animations, but no actual progress), it means
>   the quantity is unknown. This happens in a lot of situations where the
>   total number of steps to be processed is unknown due to the data, or
>   the amount of time it would take to calculate the total number of
>   items would take too long.
>
> Progress bars should also be a different subject then Time Estimates
>   as they are not the same. I have 100 things to process, so my progress
>   is between 1 and 100. How long that takes depends entirely upon what I
>   am processing. If I'm processing Invoices say, then how long it takes
>   depends a lot on what is involved with the invoice (line items,
>   calculations, other look ups).
>
> Just because it took 10 seconds to process the last one doesn't mean
>   it's going to take 10 seconds to process the next one. In order to
>   determine how much time is left, what most people do is take the
>   quantity left and multiply that by the average time it's taken so far.
>   You could apply smoothing to the average (so it doesn't jump around a
>   lot), but other then that, how else would you estimate the time? If
>   the amount of time it takes to process items is fairly even, your
>   estimate will be very accurate, if they are vastly different between
>   items, then your estimate is going to jump all over the place and be
>   wildly inaccurate.

http://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/02/13/0026234/ask-slashdot-why-is-it-so-hard-to-make-an-accurate-progress-bar

Comment: Thanks for your help, that link looks great. Keep em coming!

Comment: If I find anything I will send you the link :) spread the useful love ;)